# How to see very large gziped json file in linux using vi

Tags: filetype-json

I have a gzip multiline json file that when unzipped takes few GB of data. Each line is a stand-alone JSON object.

How can I quickly see it's content in a stream way?

Comment: I guess less would be your best bet here (I think it can handle ziped files by itself)